# What is the best PGP program, commercial products included?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

What is the best PGP program, commercial products included?

Must have:

1. Easy and streamlined email integration for common clients.
2. Easy to encrypt single files with simple GUI.
3. Some kind of trusted centralized key managing service for common PGP needs (tracking public keys, revoking keys, etc.)
4. Must be strongly GUI based. Command line features wont be used.

I am aware of the command line clients, but I need something with much better integration in a GUI enviornment. Consider price no object.

Comment: for which operating system?

Comment: "What is the best ..." should be Community Wiki.

Comment: Windows operating system support is most critical.

Answer (score 3):

See [Gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) :

> Gpg4win is an installer package for
>   Windows (2000/XP/2003/Vista) with
>   computer programs and handbooks for
>   email and file encryption. Both
>   relevant cryptography standards are
>   supported, OpenPGP and S/MIME. Gpg4win
>   and the software included with Gpg4win
>   are Free Software (among other things
>   free of charge for all commercial and
>   non-commercial purposes).
>
> You can choose all or some of the
>   following modules during installation:
>
> GnuPG:    The core; this is the actual
>   encryption tool. Kleopatra:   A
>   certificate manager for OpenPGP and
>   X.509 (S/MIME) and common crypto
>   dialogs.
>  GPA:    Another
>   certificate manager for OpenPGP and
>   X.509 (S/MIME).
>  GpgOL:   A plugin
>   for Microsoft Outlook 2003 and 2007
>   (email encryption).
>  GpgEX:   A
>   plugin for Microsoft Explorer (file
>   encryption).
>  Claws Mail:     A
>   complete email program including the
>   plugin for GnuPG.
>  Gpg4win
>   Compendium:   The new (German!)
>   documentation about Gpg4win2
>   (translation already scheduled).
>   Gpg4win for Novices:  The old English
>   handbook about Gpg4win1 (for
>   newbies).

[image]